# Can't install Java Card applets on my Smart Card

Tags: installation, applet, smartcard, javacard

I have generated a .cap file from a simple HelloWorld program that looks like this:

```
package com.oracle.jcclassic.samples.helloworld;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.Util;

public class HelloWorld extends Applet {
    private byte[] echoBytes;
    private static final short LENGTH_ECHO_BYTES = 256;
    protected HelloWorld() {
        echoBytes = new byte[LENGTH_ECHO_BYTES];
        register();
    }
    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new HelloWorld();
    }
   @Override 
   public void process(APDU apdu) {
        byte buffer[] = apdu.getBuffer();
        if ((buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] == 0) &&
                (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] == (byte) (0xA4))) {
            return;
        }

        short bytesRead = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
        short echoOffset = (short) 0;

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, echoBytes, echoOffset, bytesRead);
            echoOffset += bytesRead;
            bytesRead = apdu.receiveBytes(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
        }

        apdu.setOutgoing();
        apdu.setOutgoingLength((short) (echoOffset + 5));

        apdu.sendBytes((short) 0, (short) 5);
        apdu.sendBytesLong(echoBytes, (short) 0, echoOffset);
    }
}
```

I've used the Eclipse IDE and their provided HelloWorld classic applet sample to do that. Then I have a NXP J3H145 Smart Card on which I'd like to install my applet. I use the Global Platform Pro tool for that and write the command:

```
gp.exe -d -v -install helloworld.cap
```

I get the following result:

```
gp.exe -d -v -install helloworld.cap
# gp -d -v -install helloworld.cap
# GlobalPlatformPro v21.12.31-3-g903416f
# Running on Windows 10 10.0 amd64, Java 18.0.1.1 by Oracle Corporation
[DEBUG] TerminalManager - Processing 3 readers with null as preferred and null as ignored
[DEBUG] TerminalManager - Preferred reader: Optional.empty
SCardConnect("Broadcom Corp Contacted SmartCard 0", T=*) -> T=1, 3BDC18FF8191FE1FC38073C821136605036351000250
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 00A40400 00
A<< (0018+2) (26ms) 6F108408A000000151000000A5049F6501FF 9000
[DEBUG] GPSession - Auto-detected ISD: A000000151000000
# Warning: no keys given, defaulting to 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
[INFO] GPSession - Using card master keys with version 0 for setting up session with MAC
A>> T=1 (4+0008) 80500000 08 4E2AF49D3EFDF13F 00
A<< (0029+2) (99ms) 00008048009426073469FF03001B999689BD191E08DBB58A4F31BE3D4A 9000
[DEBUG] GPSession - KDD: 00008048009426073469
[DEBUG] GPSession - Host challenge: 4E2AF49D3EFDF13F
[DEBUG] GPSession - Card challenge: 1B999689BD191E08
[DEBUG] GPSession - Card reports SCP03 with key version 255 (0xFF)
[INFO] GPSession - Diversified card keys: ENC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 504A77) MAC=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 504A77) DEK=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F (KCV: 504A77) for SCP03
[INFO] GPSession - Session keys: ENC=196540E4A67650882195BF1BCEB78B36 MAC=09B4554BBA83417A61728B9AE76DECF7 RMAC=CB8F3FC5C52BE5A9C83A49622B195C01
[DEBUG] GPSession - Verified card cryptogram: DBB58A4F31BE3D4A
[DEBUG] GPSession - Calculated host cryptogram: 89F0CD854C3725AD
A>> T=1 (4+0016) 84820100 10 89F0CD854C3725AD58C4B201E2C601FE
A<< (0000+2) (148ms) 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F28002 0A 4F002740B169D9F9CC3A 00
A<< (0044+2) (111ms) E32A4F08A0000001510000009F700107C5039EFE80C407A0000000620001CE020100CC08A000000151000000 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F24002 0A 4F009CDA12BDBB4AD370 00
A<< (0000+2) (99ms) 6A88
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F21002 0A 4F00467F8B0AF8DAC1AE 00
A<< (0025+2) (102ms) E3174F07A00000015153509F7001018408A000000151535041 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F22002 0A 4F00510E1124D76D25E7 00
A<< (0015+2) (99ms) E30D4F07A00000015153509F700101 9000
CAP file (v2.3), contains: applets for JavaCard 3.1.0
Package: com.oracle.jcclassic.samples.helloworld A00000006203010C01 v1.0
Applet:  com.oracle.jcclassic.samples.helloworld.HelloWorld A00000006203010C0101
Import:  A0000000620101                   v1.8 javacard.framework
Import:  A0000000620001                   v1.0 java.lang
Generated by Oracle Corporation converter  [v3.1.0]
On Thu May 26 14:58:30 EEST 2022 with JDK 18.0.1.1 (Oracle Corporation)
Code size 339 bytes (1149 with debug)
SHA-256 96aaaaa6510a3bc106babdec45790831c3ea62c2e05d274e05a4999255bdc3e1
SHA-1   8afd2bd6d08fff180d6949189399928ff41a7371
A>> T=1 (4+0030) 84E60200 1E 09A00000006203010C0108A000000151000000000000268DB924E83229B2
A<< (0001+2) (113ms) 00 9000
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
A<< (0000+2) (698ms) 6403
Error: LOAD failed: 0x6403
SCardDisconnect("Broadcom Corp Contacted SmartCard 0", true) tx:399/rx:150 in 1s663ms
```

So, the process ends with the error 6403, and my applet is not installed. I have found that the APDU response code 6403 means "CAP MINOR", but I have no idea what it is about. CAP file minor version? I can see in the print-out above the following line:

```
CAP file (v2.3), contains: applets for JavaCard 3.1.0
```

Does that mean that there are some problem with different versions? But I found in my Smart Card specification (https://www.cardlogix.com/product/nxp-jcop3-j3h145-java-card-3-0-4-dual-interface) that it supports JavaCard version v3.

I also tried downloading my applet to my card using the PyApduTool (http://javacardos.com/javacardforum/viewtopic.php?t=38). I got the following error message:

```
Download Cap error: GP init update failed. recv: 67 00
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with my code or my actions and why I can't install any applets on my card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please compile with the exact version. Normal Java is relatively flexible when it comes to differences in minor versions. The dynamic linking simply happens by method signature, i.e. the name and parameters within the class file.

However, CAP files are *pre-linked* during conversion. That means that all the methods in a class are enumerated, and the byte code simply refers to members by value, not by name.

If the API changes then the enumeration changes and the byte code would link to the wrong members within a class. It is therefore very important that the minor version is correct as well.

Comment: Thanks so much, Maarten! I found out how to change the target platform version when generating the CAP file, changed it to my card's version of 3.0.4, and now I can install my applet! Your help is hugely appreciated!